# Simple GCD program in c, having trouble filtering correct user input from scanner

Tags: c, string, input, conditional-statements

My program prompts the user for two positive integers to compute their GCD. From the scanner, the program does not accept any input that is not a positive integer and instead prompts the user again.

Most of my code already works correctly. My issue is that my program takes two negative integer inputs before asking for another positive integer. Other characters work just fine. Any tips to solve this minor issue?

## Source code

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int temp1, temp2, A, B, C;
    char str[256];

    while(1){
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        while(scanf(" %d", &A)!=1 || A <= 0) {
            scanf(" %s", str);
            printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        }
        if(A > 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    //same loop to get B

    //compute GCD of A and B

    //print out answer

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Sample Output

---

```
Enter a positive integer: -5
-6
Please enter a positive integer: -7
-8
Please enter a positive integer: k
Please enter a positive integer: s
Please enter a positive integer: d
Please enter a positive integer: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program wants to read something because you told so.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int temp1, temp2, scanf_ret, A, B, C;

    while(1){
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        while((scanf_ret=scanf(" %d", &A))!=1 || A <= 0) {
            if(scanf_ret<0) {
                puts("got unexpected EOF");
                return 1;
            }
            if(scanf_ret==0)scanf(" %*s");
            printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        }
        if(A > 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    //same loop to get B

    //compute GCD of A and B

    //print out answer

    return 0;
}
```

In this code,

- If `scanf_ret` is `1`, it means the read was successful and there is no need to consume garbage.
- If `scanf_ret` is `0`, it means there are some obstacles that cannot be read as integer, so remove them.
- If `scanf_ret` is negative, it means it is the end of input, so exit program.

Also note that you are not to store the garbage, so buffer overrun can be avoided.

Comment: @Ryan, you should accept his answer, i actually find it the best that describes the `scanf ` issue.